# Google Charts adding options to the charts

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am using this code for creating charts and it works but I need to add the options too just don't know where to add them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualizationHourlyChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ // Create and populate the data table.
            ['Date - Hour:Minute', 'Cares', 'Bikes', 'Both'],

            <?php
            while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
                extract($row);
                echo "['Date: ($dateandtime) - {$hour}:{$minute}', {$cars}, {$bikes}, {$both}],";
            }
            ?>
        ]);

            new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('mydiv')).   // Create and draw the visualization.
            draw(data, {legend: 'bottom', title:"titles here"});
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualizationHourlyChart);
</script>
```

And what I want the do is add All the code below into the code above.

```
 var options = {  
   //options go here
});
```

Where do I add the options?

Comment: You did add the options in the draw method, didn't you? `draw(data, { here are your options })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are the second param of the draw method.

```
var options = {
  legend: 'bottom',
  title:"titles here"
  };

chart.draw(data, options);
```